# Real vector bundles on $S^{7}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Is it true  that  $\pi_{6}(O(n))=0$ for all n?
Equivalently,  are all real  bundles on $S^{7}$ trivial?

Comment: Just some comments that you are no doubt aware of, but than can be useful to some:
1. Because $SO(n)$ is the connected component of $O(n)$ containing the identity, $\pi_k SO(n) = \pi_k O(n)$.
2. Because of Bott periodicity theorem, $\pi_6 SO(n) = 0$ forall $n \geq 8$.
3. $SO(1)$ is trivial, $SO(2)$ is a circle: no $\pi_6$ there.
Conclusion: the question boils down to: "is $\pi_6 SO(n)$ nontrivial for some $n \in \{3,4,5,6,7\}$?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the covering space $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ given by the quaternions (cf. [this document](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/iganev/cover.pdf), for example), we know that the universal cover of $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to $SU(2) \simeq S^3$.

This implies that $\pi_6 SO(3) \simeq \pi_6 S^3 \simeq \mathbb Z/12$ (according to [that table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table_of_homotopy_groups)).

So there is a nontrivial rank 3 bundle on $S^7$.

---

Once the few remarks I made in my comment are clear, [this article](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kervnon.pdf) by Michel Kervaire gives the definitive answer (p. 162):
$$\pi_6 SO(3) \simeq \mathbb Z/12\qquad \pi_6 SO(4) \simeq (\mathbb Z/12)^2\qquad \pi_6 SO(5) = \pi_6 SO(6) = \pi_6 SO(7) = 0.$$

Note that $\pi_6SO(4)$ also comes from the quaternions: indeed, they also give the universal cover $SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SO(4)$, so $\pi_6(SO(4)) \simeq (\pi_6(S^3))^2 \simeq (\mathbb Z/12)^2$.

Comment: Many  thanks  for  your interesting answer and  useful comment.